# How to variably add to arrayOf<T>() in Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have reached a problem while making an application to plot a bar chart depending on user inputs. In some constructor I need to pass:

```
arrayOf<DataPoint>
```

but the problem is that I do not know in advanced (before runtime) how many elements I will have so I cannot set it manually in a way:

```
arrayOf<DataPoint> ( DataPoint(0.0, 1.0), DataPoint(1.0, 5.0), etc.)
```

I need to do this depending on user input (so some for loop to go through elements).

How can I achieve something like this?

```
arrayOf<DataPoint> ( for ( (i, v) in some_data.withIndex() ) DataPoint(i, v), ... )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
val array = Array(some_data.size) { i -> DataPoint(i, some_data[i]) }
```

or

```
val array = some_data.mapIndexed { i, v -> DataPoint(i, v) }.toTypedArray()
```